# how to put a line under 2 elements which have padding

Tags: html

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>xxxx</title>
    <style>.center {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
       
      }</style>
      <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="image" />

</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding-left: 500px;">
    
        <img src="image" alt="image" style="float:left ;" width="50" height="50" class="center">
        
        <h2 style="text-align: center;font-family: sans-serif;color: rgb(81, 81, 133);float:left ;">xxxx</h2>
    <hr>
    </div> 
 
</body>
</html>
```

this is what I have so far but whenever I try that the line goes to the top right what can I do to put it directly below the two elements

[image]

Comment: [A horizontal rule might be interesting for you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr)

Comment: We need to see your HTML and CSS code so we can spot what you have done wrong.

Comment: [float:left;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) is what is responsible for this behaviour

Comment: That's the behavior of the float, don't use it unless you have no other choice, and if you do so, use with clearfix. But if you want to know why this happens it's because float creates spaces that elements can use to place themselves, based on their size. so if you give the hr width:100%, you see your problem is gone, but the small hr can fit itself to those empty spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use CSS classes and put your styling separately, because it creates cleaner HTML code.

`padding-left` isn't great because that only fits your own screen resolution. I just added `text-align: right` to push the whole shebang to the right, assuming that's what you wanted.

I added a container div and styled it with a border. Had to give it a width.

You shouldn't style using floats, unless you know what you're doing. `display: flex` or `display: grid` is what you're after when it comes to placing the elements on the right place.

```html
<html>

<style>
  header {
    text-align: right;
  }

  header > .border-bottom-container {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;      /* align vertically */
    justify-content: center;  /* align horizontally */
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
  }

  header img {
    width: 50px
    height: 50px;
  }

  header h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: rgb(81, 81, 133);
  }
</style>


<body>
  <header>
    <div class="border-bottom-container">
      <img src="image.png" alt="image">
      <h2>xxxx</h2>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`clear: left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) property on `hr` tag

> It is not advised to use inline CSS

> Also the float property creates unwanted(unexpected) behaviors so you can use `flex` or `grid` property instead

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>xxxx</title>
  <style>
    .center {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="image" />

</head>

<body>
  <div style="padding-left: 500px;">

    <img src="image" alt="image" style="float:left ;" width="50" height="50" class="center">

    <h2 style="text-align: center;font-family: sans-serif;color: rgb(81, 81, 133);float:left;">xxxx</h2>
    <hr style="clear:left">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest you wrap them in a div and then add the line to the div itself.

Comment: yes i have tried that but it did not work